# Error with oracle ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle10g Express edition and I tried to create this tables but an Error appeared and I need some help fixing the "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" problem. I searched for a solution to this error and it looks like the main reason is not the "missing right parenthesis" but I still can't fix the code.

```
CREATE TABLE Pays
(
    codePays NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_Pays PRIMARY KEY,
    nomPays VARCHAR(20)
);
CREATE TABLE Equipe
(
    codeEquipe NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_Equipe PRIMARY KEY,
    nomEquipe VARCHAR(4),
);
CREATE TABLE Etape
(
    numEtape NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_Etape PRIMARY KEY,
);
CREATE TABLE Coureur
(
    numCoureur NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_Coureur PRIMARY KEY,
    codeEquipe NUMBER(4),
    codePays NUMBER(4),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Equipe_Coureur FOREIGN KEY(codeEquipe) REFERENCES Equipe(codeEquipe);
    CONSTRAINT FK_Pays_Coureur FOREIGN KEY(codePays) REFERENCES Pays(codePays);
);
```

Comment: Remove semicolons for last tables fk's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two semicolons in the code for creating the `Coureur` table.  You also have a dangling comma in the code for creating the `Equipe` table.  Replace your code with this:

```
CREATE TABLE Pays
(
    codePays NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_Pays PRIMARY KEY,
    nomPays VARCHAR(20)
);
CREATE TABLE Equipe
(
    codeEquipe NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_Equipe PRIMARY KEY,
    nomEquipe VARCHAR(4)
);
CREATE TABLE Etape
(
    numEtape NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_Etape PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Coureur
(
    numCoureur NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_Coureur PRIMARY KEY,
    codeEquipe NUMBER(4),
    codePays NUMBER(4),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Equipe_Coureur FOREIGN KEY(codeEquipe) REFERENCES Equipe(codeEquipe),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Pays_Coureur FOREIGN KEY(codePays) REFERENCES Pays(codePays)
);
```

Here is what I believe is happening leading to the exact error you are seeing.  Your Oracle workbench is parsing the `Coureur` table definition, and it hits a semicolon on the line for the `FK_Equipe_Courer` constraint.  It interprets this as the end of the table definition, but it doesn't see a closing right parenthesis before this semicolon, so it gives you the error you see.

Comment: Both semi colons need to go, I think.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Thanks...he also has a trailing comma in the `Equipe` table.  But the bigger question is doesn't his SQL editor point these things out?

Comment: I deleted some columns when I posted the question on stackoverflow so the code is not so long.. so I didn't noticed that .. In oracle, I have the correct code but with semicolons for last tables fk's.